# Is there a PoC empty OS?

Tags: osdev

For fun i'd like to write code that runs on OSless hardware. I think writing code that will run in a VM (like VMware or virtualbox) would be good. However i don't want to start from scratch. I'd like the C++ runtime to be available. Something that allows me to read/write (maybe FAT32 filesystem code). Graphics for text and if i can graphics for drawing on screen (pixel by pixel. sdl support would be a bonus but not essential).

I'll write my own threads if i want them. I'll write everything else (that i want to use) needed for an OS. I just want a basic filesystem, gfx and keyboard/mouse support.

Comment: Linux is good :) Apart from that, I only know about Singularity and CosmOS - those are for .NET, though.

Comment: What are you up to, anyway? You're asking some interesting questions. Anyway, check out http://www.qnx.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the list of projects on osdev.org - (http://wiki.osdev.org/Projects) - most of these are hobbyist, open-source and range from just-a-bootsector through to proper threads/graphics/terminal support.

Answer (score 0):

[Minix3](http://www.minix3.org/) targets your desires pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at [OSKit](http://www.cs.utah.edu/flux/oskit/) (links to source code on this site are dead but there is a mirror [here](http://savannah.nongnu.org/cvs/?group=oskit)). Unfortunately, OSKit has no support for C++ but using [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/C++#Full_C.2B.2B_Runtime_Support_Using_libgcc_And_libsupc.2B.2B) information you may be able to use GCC libraries.